# Styling a checkbox with css only

Tags: html, css, checkbox, hover

Styling a checkbox with css only. Checkbox definition uses shorthand definition and not span and label to define the text.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
Hello world!<input name="status" id="status" type="checkbox" />
```

I would like to see a blue border when the user hovers over the checkbox.
What is diffirent for my question is that it uses short hand notation. There is no explicit label, or span element that you can manipulate to get a certain effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css?rq=1

Comment: @Alexis, The question is not duplicate to the one you link, because in my case I use the shorthand notation for an input element.

Comment: Well its different -  if you cannot help please don't answer.

Comment: I think you will need an element wrapping `Hello world!`, as `input` does not accept `:before` or `:after`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to styling the checkbox itself, you can use the following CSS (for Firefox and Safari/Chrome) to unset standard input elements appearance and then design them yourself (compare http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp):

```
input[type="checkbox"] {    
-moz-appearance:none; /* Firefox */
-webkit-appearance:none; /* Safari and Chrome */
... [your definitions]
}
```

Styling of the checkbox AND the text next to it, will not work without a wrapping element, as @sodawillow has pointed out.
You could use jQuery to generate a wrapping element around each checkbox and its preceding text:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function{
 $(this, this.prev()).wrapAll('<li class="checkbox_wrapper"></li>');
});
$('li.checkbox_wrapper').wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
```

Then you can use the checkbox_wrapper class to design the whole thing.

Comment: At best the wrapper can be an unordered list.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel, you gave me a good idea about having the jQuery handle the wrapper.

Comment: Of course, the wrapper can be anything. I'm changing the example so you get an unordered list. You would have to add a line for the <ul> - tag. Please mark as answered if this solves your problem! Thanks. :-)